# Fast switching with RTL inverter

Tags: switching

I have for some days worked with an RTL inverter and an totem pole drive to drive a high voltage MOSFET. And I am happy with the result except for one thing the rise time on the inverter output (from ON to OFF). Here I have to choose between large power consumption or large dV/dt. And in the application for which this is to be used I do not have the possibility of high power consumption bur I still need a large dV/dt output. I have tried to come up with a circuit that bypasses R1 and releases charge from Vcc to Aout, but has not succeeded does anyone have a suggestion?. 
In the simulation is three run with 1k, 5k and 10k, as seen the 1k gives the best result highest dV/dt.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Make C1 bigger. You need lots of charge, to quickly turn off the inverter. The voltage gain is large, thus the Miller Multiplication is large (to charge up the collector-base capacitance). And experiment with a real "Baker Clamp" by adding another diode, in series with the base.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf clearly not my area of expertise, but what if the CMOS pair wasn't designed symmetrically?

Comment: Even after Q2 turns off, R1 has to pull all the parasitic capacitance on the collector up, as well as providing current for the totem pole.  The time constant for 20pF and 10K is 200ns, so this topology might not be the best for the application.  Have you considered a gate driver IC?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf A low-Vf schottky between base and collector ought to have a similar effect as a Baker clamp, since it will turn on well before the base-collector junction does. I don't think adding a second diode will help all that much (though, I could be wrong!).

Comment: Thanks for good and valuable input.
The driver will be in a 200C(392F) application, so the choice is discrete or a monolithic driver at a really high price!

Comment: The problem the junction capacitance as John D mentions. If I increase the speed-up capacitance (C1) I will be punished with too much charge in the junction and when turning off, the cap need to discharge. As I have a miller cap on 8pF (Cgc = 8pF) and Cgs = 25pF in the SPICE model and the totem pole will also give me something on this node. 200pF on the speed-up seem give the best results. Marcus, I don’t know if the CMOS output is the best to use here. RogerA.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a gate driver IC is appropriate (certainly lower parts-count) as @JohnD has suggested. Most drivers provide charging currents well over an amp for both rising and falling edges provide large dV/dt, and some have low quiescent current draw.

That said, you might improve the rise time of your circuit with a supplementary PNP pull-up transistor that is active for a very short time, pulling the NPN collector up with a short, fast, large pulse of current. This allows you to use a larger pull-up resistor (R1=10k).
Note that the PNP Q4 starts to draw about 10ma current after a time (about 0.5 us). This static current may not be wanted for a low power driver, especially if the PWM input pulse from logic source V3 has low duty-cycle...(much less a problem at high duty cycle).[image: pnp supplementary driver added]
A diode D3 might be a safe idea so that ramping up V1 to its +20V doesn't fry the logic driver with a killing pulse through C2.
Note that a faster switch Q1 is used rather than 2n2222.
R3 is chosen with care to set the static current of Q4 to something around 10ma. Since this current is very dependent on Q4's \$ H_{fe} \$ this quicky design is a bit too simple. When parts-count climbs, that monolithic IC driver becomes more attractive.

Comment: While I certainly appreciate the effort you put into this, you don't get any points for scrunching your schematic down to the point of making it essentially unreadable. And I agree about using a gate driver IC -- it would use a proper current mirror as the load for Q1, which is too many transistors for a discrete solution.

Comment: @DaveTweed criticism accepted. Can I blame a low-res screen (and eyes)? A fault I shall try to overcome.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly I think I will use it the way you have done it. The reason I choose to use discrete components is that 200C monolithic drivers are very expensive. Thanks!